# The syntax for pattern matching using LIKE and OR in typo3

Tags: doctrine-orm, typo3, typo3-8.x

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 
               'SELECT * 
                FROM table 
                WHERE ((title LIKE  "%'.$search_key.'%" ) 
                   OR (name like "%'.$search_key.'%")) 
                ORDER BY UID DESC 
                LIMIT 4');
```

I'm trying to convert the above code to use with querybuilder.
I tried alot. for eg:

`$queryBuilder->expr()->like('title', "%'.$search_key.'%")`

but it didnt work. Anybody please help me.

the whole code is:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
                        ->getQueryBuilderForTable('table');

$statement = $queryBuilder->select('*')
                    ->from('table')

                    ->orderBy('uid' ,'DESC') 

                    ->where(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->like('title', "%'.$search_key.'%")
)          
                    ->execute();
```

Comment: Can you please provide us your whole of the $querybuilder part to make sure you did not forget anything before / after.

Comment: $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
                        ->getQueryBuilderForTable('table');
       
$statement = $queryBuilder->select('*')
                    ->from('table')
                   
                    ->orderBy('uid' ,'DESC') 
                   // ->setFirstResult(1) 
                    ->where(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->like('title', "%'.$search_key.'%")
)          
                    ->execute();

Answer (score 3):

Never ever forget to quote properly!
A casual "like" example can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#escapelikewildcards

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation is wrong, you should use single quote and not double quote:
`->where($queryBuilder->expr()->like('title', '%' . $search_key . '%')`

Comment: Your suggestion is easier to follow if you add an explanation why one should use single instead of double quotes.

Comment: well, it's just because he used single quote for the first argument, you should have some consistency in your code.